# Extracting data in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a text here

> TK 8600xxxx8888|GD: -250,000VND 28/01/21 18:41|SD:50,035VND|ND: Ck - Ma giao dich/ Trace 521298 -52210000086554

How can I put all that data in the database?
Ex:

> TK = 8600xxxx8888; GD = -250000; SD = 50035; ND = Ck; Trace = 521298, Cus = 52210000086554

Comment: please explain better your problem and what you tried to solve it

Comment: Can you tell us what the rules are for extracting what we see in your expected output?

Comment: The rule is that the text always stays the same and the numbers change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$string = "TK 8600xxxx8888|GD: -250,000VND 28/01/21 18:41|SD:50,035VND|ND: Ck - Ma giao dich/ Trace 521298 -52210000086554";

$string_array = explode("|", $string);

$TX = substr(strrchr($string_array[0], " "), 1);

$GD = substr($string_array[1], 0, strrpos( $string_array[1], ' ') );
$GD = substr($GD, 0, strrpos( $GD, ' ') );
$GD = str_replace('VND', '', $GD);
$GD = str_replace(',', '', $GD);
$GD = str_replace('GD: ', '', $GD);

$SD = str_replace('VND', '', $string_array[2]);
$SD = str_replace(',', '', $SD);
$SD = str_replace('SD:', '', $SD);

$ND = $string_array[3];
$ND = str_replace('ND:', '', $ND);
$ND = substr($ND, 0, strrpos( $ND, ' - ') );
$ND = str_replace(' ', '', $ND);

$Trace = $string_array[3];
$Trace = substr(strrchr($Trace, "/"), 1);
$Trace = $Cus = str_replace(' Trace ', '', $Trace);
$Trace = substr($Trace, 0, strrpos( $Trace, ' -') );

$Cus = substr(strrchr($Cus, " "), 1);

echo $TX . "<br />" . $GD . "<br />" . $SD . "<br />" . $ND . "<br />" . $Trace . "<br />" . $Cus;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet may help you to achieve that goal:

```
<?php
$txt = "TK: 8600xxxx8888|GD: -250,000VND 28/01/21 18:41|SD:50,035VND|ND: Ck - Ma giao dich/ Trace 521298 -52210000086554";
$arr = [];
foreach(explode("|", $txt) as $t){
    $var = explode(":", $t);
    $arr[$var[0]] = $var[1];
}

foreach($arr as $a){
    echo $a . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: This is Wrong. It will returns : 
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Other_Projects\Testing\index.php on line 7
8600xxxx8888
-250,000VND

Ck

Comment: @JohnDoe in the question comments, he/she said "The rule is that the text always stays the same and the numbers change", if the text have same patten above code actually works.

Comment: It will not work for the current string even.

Comment: @JohnDoe does your pattern like this? "TK: 8600xxxx8888|GD: -250,000VND 28/01/21 18:41|SD:50,035VND|ND: Ck - Ma giao dich/ Trace 521298 -52210000086554"

Comment: it runs, but doesn't return the full data I would like :(

Comment: @Kriss please test my code in https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_compiler